# Where has the 'distance matrix' tool gone in QGIS 2.18.0?

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix, ftools

Today I installed QGIS 2.18.0 and I wondered, where has my 'distance matrix' - Tool gone?

Comment: I have it under vector/analysys tools

Answer (score 2):

Some of the tools have been moved to the processing toolbox:
[image: distance matrix_processing]

And after checking, it is also in the normal menus:
[image: Distance matrix_menu]

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, was reported in [Built-in tools missing from Vector menu](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15265). So, you need to delete ~/qgis2 folder (or .qgis2 in OS X) and open again QGIS.

Be careful, make a backup of your python plugins (they are in the same folder).

Comment: Perfect! Delete ~/qgis2 folder solved my problem. The tools appeared. Thanks a lot!